# How can I find out how much physical space a record (BLOB) in a sqlite database uses?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using Ditto as my clipboard history manager and the database is now at about 5.5 gig.  that's probably too big ;o)  After deleting a bunch of screenshots and doing a compact and repair on the database, it is still too big.

I'm looking at the table definition below for the main data table.

```
CREATE TABLE Data(lID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, lParentID INTEGER, strClipBoardFormat TEXT, ooData BLOB)
```

is there a way in sqlite (version 3.7.13) to find out how much space a record is using so I can delete it/them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length(ooData)` should do the trick.

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

> *length(X):* For a string value X, the length(X) function returns the
>   number of characters (not bytes) in X prior to the first NUL
>   character. Since SQLite strings do not normally contain NUL
>   characters, the length(X) function will usually return the total
>   number of characters in the string X. **For a blob value X, length(X)
>   returns the number of bytes in the blob. If X is NULL then length(X)
>   is NULL. If X is numeric then length(X) returns the length of a string
>   representation of X.**

So your query would look something like this, I believe:

```
SELECT id_field, length(blobData) AS size, blobdata FROM your_table 
WHERE blobData IS NOT NULL
```

Since you're only really interested in the "biggest" files in the database, you'll probably want to only choose the biggest of the files, so you'll want to add a constraint like this

```
AND size > 1000000;
```